# wlan0 not showing up in ifconfig/iwconfig

Tags: wireless, windows-10, hp, ifconfig

I've tried all the other threads and nothing is working. I'm very new to Ubuntu. I'm trying to use reaver and when I attempt it says

```
[-] Failed to retrieve a MAC address for interface 'wlan0'!
```

So I do `ifconfig` and get (running internet off phone)

```
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.10.3  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 172.20.10.15
        inet6 fe80::250d:ea01:c7e:b2f5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether de:0c:5c:ab:f3:29  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.120.168.140  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 100.120.175.255
        inet6 fe80::51e1:4e13:b623:444b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:ff:ca:58:32:ea  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        loop  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

```
$ iwconfig

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions.

eth2      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wifi0     no wireless extensions.

wifi1     no wireless extensions.

wifi2     no wireless extensions.
```

How can I get my wlan0 back?

Answer (score 4):

Are you running Kali, or any other Linux distribution inside of Virtualbox, VMWare?

If you're running Linux in a virtual container you need an external wireless card. Also your on an HP notebook that was built to run Windows 10, you would need to live boot from a USB or CD, and try configuring your network adapter with `ifconfig` then, also your wireless network adapter might have a different name other than `wlan0` (Kali configures this).

INFO: The network card ("wifi card") that's in your PC may not even support packet injection, or monitor mode.

*Also make sure that if you put wlan0 into monitor mode you run these commands:*

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Verify that you put `wlan0` up before you try running reaver

**You may have not properly brought up your wireless network adapter `wlan0` You should restart your computer, run the above commands to configure your network adapter, and rerun reaver. If that didn't work continue below:**

**INFO: If there is a hardware switch that controls your network adapter switch it on before executing the following command**

The command is usually:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up ; sudo rfkill unblock all ; sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

If that is not successful, try restarting your PC (at bootup if you have a wireless switch on your PC switch it on now), and repeating the above command. You may also want to try:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 ; sudo ifconfig wlan0 down ; sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

If it still is not working, the order of precedence with the above commands matters. If you didn't bring your network card `wlan0` back up before running reaver, restart your PC and try again. You also might need to look into `rfkill` (radio frequency kill), and unblock your network adapter by `sudo rfkill unblock all ; sudo rfkill unblock wifi` (run command a few times, and restart PC)

If all else fails, don't give up the world of IT and Cyber security is amazing. Learn the basics, look up *how to install Ubuntu from USB*, or if you want to skip learning and use tools, `how to download Kali Linux on USB* after that look up *hp boot from USB*

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons for this issue is missing Linux headers.

Try all the above mentioned answers. If those didn't help you, try this solution.

The solution is to simply install Linux headers using the command below :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Then update and upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update && upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem some weeks ago and here is how I solved it.

In my case, when I used `ifconfig`, `wlan0` was not listed.

So I connected to the internet using a USB cable (tethering), opened a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
Ran this command:

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then rebooted my computer and it worked

Comment: there is no evidence that this could help the OP - we don't know whether this package has the driver for their wireless card

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried everything and nothing works maybe you are missing this package

> linux-firmware

**Ubuntu:**

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-firmware
```

**Arch:**

```
sudo pacman -S linux-firmware
```